# Xamarin Insight License

Tags: xamarin, licensing

I’m trying to add an app for Insight and I have an Enterprise trial license, but it says:

"An active Xamarin Platform license is required to add applications to Insights."

Is it possible to create an Insight app with the trial license?

Is the Xamarin Insight license included in the Visual Studio License?
If yes, Is it the same to buy a Professional or Enterprise License to use Xamarin Insight?

Comment: Insights has been shutdown - I believe it is still available for existing Enterprise customers, but not new users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a licensing question. This should be asked of Microsoft, not of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Insights is a separate product that, as far as I know, was never included in a Visual Studio license. With the merge from Xamarin inside Microsoft Insights will be shut down and some of the features will be available in HockeyApp. But in the long run even HockeyApp will going off in Visual Studio Mobile Center.

At the time of writing, only existing customers can create new apps in Xamarin Insights. So I assume, if you do not have any apps currently in Insights you are not able to create a new one.